# Adding fields midway while creating a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I need to create a CSV file from a database table that holds JSON data in one of the table's columns. Each line in the table can hold a JSON with different variables.

The CSV I create should have fields for all variables in all lines.

**Example:**

Line 1 in db table : `{"height":100,"weight":50}`

Line 2 in db table: `{"color":"red"}`

Line 3 in db table: `{"color":"blue","height":75}`

CSV to be created:

```
height,weight,color
100,50,
,,red
,75,blue
```

Since the table may include hundreds of thousands of lines, I would like to know if there is a way to add fields midway while reading lines from the table and creating the CSV without reading the entire table once to get all fields and then again to write the CSV.

I've used CSVHelper https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ for handling CSV operations in the past but I saw no option for my scenario.

Comment: So the *real* question is how to flatten the badly stored data without reading all data. You can't do that with CsvHelper or *any* flat file exporter. A CSV file is just a text file, with Values, Separated by Commas. You can't insert strings to a text file, only overwrite an existing range or append text. To "insert" you'd have to first move all the data after the insertion point to the right. That's a lot more expensive than flattening the data with eg SQL, or in-memory.

Comment: What database are you using? Most databases have JSON support which could be used to unpack the JSON data. You'd need to know the actual fields to get a flat result though. Otherwise you can unpack the data into multiple rows (long format), then pivot the data in memory (wide format). Or you could use eg Python and Pandas to load the existing data and unpack the data in memory

Comment: In one iteration of the table read (meaning when reading one row), you would need to read that JSON object, deserialize the JSON to a C# object with properties height, weight, color, wherein a missing value is projected to null or empty string, and then write that line to the CSV file. Its a little messy and idk how well optimized it will be

Comment: What you really need is to take those JSON objects, and actually create a table in db with the columns height, weight, color. Idk who came up with that scheme you have there but you were dealt a bad hand

Comment: _"Idk who came up with that scheme you have there but you were dealt a bad hand"_ - As _always_ this most probably was (or at least looked like) a good idea when that person came up with it. The hand went bad when some idiot promised the customer they could have a csv export of that data. (IDK if that's the scenario here, but that's exactly what we as devs have to deal with on a daily basis. Ideas that are designed and crafted specifically for purpose A now must be bent and distorted for purpose B ...)

Comment: @adinas Is this a one-time thing or will you have to do this regularly?

Comment: @Fildor unfortunately, it is not a one-time thing.

Comment: @Narish You gave me an idea wherein I would create, lets say 100 headers, and as I find new variables, I set them to the next header. and when the export is done, I just change the first line of headers to the names of the variables...

Comment: Are you willing to modify your CSV format?  CsvHelper supports reading multiple data sets in one file, see [Reading Multiple Data Sets](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-multiple-data-sets/).  So you could write using the same format: write an empty line and a new list of headers every time the set of columns changes.

Comment: If it's a recurring issue, you may want to consider a (better?) different table schema. Are the JSON properties completely arbitrary or a known set?

Comment: @adinas see the problem is, you want columns to properly line up, so in a sense, you would really want to know upfront the shape of the object that will be mapping to a row of the table. Say for example, you have 10 rows of color, and then weight + weight, then either the 1st 10 rows are missing 2 end columns, or the 11th row is missing its 1st column. Its really tragic that whoever did this couldn't just do something like `{"height":100,"weight":50, "color": null }`. I think your best shot is to try and create that object with all possible rows, and then do the process

Comment: @narish I don't know the shape upfront and I am trying to save a double pass on the data (the first one for getting all the shapes)... Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @adinas yea this sounds like hell....Its really hard to do an data table without this sort of information, and a CSV ought to be a well formed data table. I don't think you really have a choice, you are going to need to do some sort of double pass because you are going to need to know what those keys are. You should genuinely consider testing out Roberto's answer. This is going to take some experimentation and analysis

Comment: @Narish - you could avoid two passes through the data by writing the rows to a temp file, then writing the discovered headers + copy in the rows to the final file.  But a CSV file is just a text file so there's no way to prepend the header row without copying the entire subsequent contents.

Comment: Personally? I would make a seperate, small console app just for analysis. Setup the db connection, run `SELECT DISTINCT JsonCol FROM Db` and query that to a list of strings. From there, deserialize each to `Dictionary<string, string>`, and then get all the keys into a HashSet you know will get the full listing of possible column names. You really don't want to do something like that one the fly every single time, so this analysis is meant to put the issue to bed once and for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code generate the required output from a list of strings containing json data. You could complete it reading data from database:

```cs
public string GetCsv(string[] jsonValues) {

    var objectsAsDictionary = jsonValues.Select(_ =>
        JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,object>>(_)).ToArray();

    using var textWriter =    new StringWriter();
    using var csv = new CsvWriter(textWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var properties = objectsAsDictionary.SelectMany(_ => _.Keys)
        .Distinct().ToArray();

    foreach (var property in properties) {
        csv.WriteField(property);
    }
    csv.NextRecord();
    foreach (var item in objectsAsDictionary) {
        foreach (var property in properties) {
            object value = null;
            item.TryGetValue(property, out value);
            csv.WriteField(value);
        }
        csv.NextRecord();
    }
    return textWriter.ToString();
}
```

This is a test that check the output:

```cs
var class1 = new Class1();
var rows = new[] {
    "{\"height\":100,\"weight\":50}",
    "{\"color\":\"red\"}",
    "{\"color\":\"blue\",\"height\":75}"
};

var result = class1.GetCsv(rows);
var expected = "height,weight,color" + Environment.NewLine +
"100,50," + Environment.NewLine +
",,red" + Environment.NewLine +
"75,,blue" + Environment.NewLine;
Assert.Equal(expected, result);
```

### Version with an incremental approach

The following code could be used if the requirement can change regarding the leading delimiter of first rows.

In this case each value could be processed in an incremental way and the header is added only at the end.

For simplicity I don't include DB access, but the enumerable parameter could be replaced by a data reader.

```cs
public string GetCsv(IEnumerable<string> jsonValues) {
    var properties = new List<string>();        

    using var textWriter = new StringWriter();
    using var csv = new CsvWriter(textWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);      

    foreach (var jsonValue in jsonValues) {
        var item = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonValue);            
        foreach (var property in item.Keys) {
            if (!properties.Contains(property)) {
                properties.Add(property);
            }
        }
        foreach (var property in properties) {
            object value = null;
            item.TryGetValue(property, out value);
            csv.WriteField(value);
        }
        csv.NextRecord();
    }
    
    return string.Join(csv.Configuration.Delimiter, properties) + Environment.NewLine +
        textWriter.ToString();
}
```

In this case I don't need to read all data at once, but I added columns each time that I found a new property.

The result would be the following (note that the second row doesn't include the final comma):

```
height,weight,color
100,50
,,red
75,,blue
```

Eventually a further processing could add missing commas to first rows.

Comment: Thanks Roberto, I think your solution assumes all the data is loaded into a variable which is not an option since my table may contain hundreds of thousands or even millions of rows and loading them all would consume too much memory. I need to read the rows one by one and process them one by one

Comment: Hi @adinas, check if the alternative that I added in the answer could work for you

Comment: Your code looks very compelling. I appreciate your help. I'm not able to test it until Sunday though but will get back to you then. Cheers.